# Result of replacing $1$ to $n$ in pairs by the sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, arithmetic, invariance

I have the following problem:

> Alice writes the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \ldots, n$ on a blackboard.  Bob selects two of these numbers,  erases both of them,  and writes down their sum on the blackboard.  For example, if Bob chose the numbers 3 and 4, the blackboard would contain the numbers $1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, \ldots, n\quad$  ($3$ and $4$ are removed from the list and $7$ is appended to the list)
> Bob continues until there is only one number left on the board.  What are the possible values of that number in terms of $n$?

I have tried using brute force on this problem with smaller values of $n$, and I seem to obtain that the number left on the blackboard is $\dfrac{n(n + 1)}{2}$. However, I cannot rigorously prove this, and I do not know if there are other possible values for the number. I would appreciate your help with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: An idea to get started is we know that $1+2+3+4+...+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ (sum of arithmetic sequence). Can you argue that your process is simply adding up all the numbers - each one exactly once - to get this result? You're adding up the numbers in pairs, and then continuing to add until you've added them all. That sounds reasonable to me

Comment: You've started the right way, making small examples.  Now ask yourself these questions.  What does $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ represent, in terms of the numbers originally on the board, and how does the sum of the numbers of the board change after Bob makes an operation?

Comment: Edited to clarify, as it seems some posters were confused (deleted comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the sum of numbers on the black board do not change after each turn.
For example, when consider the numbers $1,2,3,4$. If we erase $3$ and $4$ and replace it with $7$ then the remaining numbers will be $1,2,7$. Notice that the sum of numbers is same for both cases.

So the last number will be the sum of all numbers on the board at the beginning.

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: The same sort of thing can be done with any operation that is commutative (so that the pairs of numbers removed don't need to have an order) and associative (so that the order of the chosen pairs doesn't matter).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

As Bob continues till the last number, by then the total sum would be $1+2+...+n= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ (the terms maybe added in different order, clearly). This is a standard formula and can be proved by induction. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. Thank you!